# How can I print a value from dictionary on the below code?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, key

I'm working on a code that takes data from different excel workbooks and someone recommended me to put those data into dictionary. Here is the code:

```
d={}
for file in range(len(filenames)):
    d[f'{file}'] = pd.read_excel(filenames[file], nrows = 32, usecols="A:D").fillna("")
```

The problem is I don't know how to print a specific value from my dictionary now.

`print(d.keys())` shows me an answer: `dict_keys(['0', '1'])`

The code below works fine:

```
for key in d:
  print (d[key])
```

But when I write: `print(d[1])` I get an error `"KeyError: 1"`

Comment: Your keys are strings. Try `d['1']`

Comment: Thank you Andrej. You are correct. Is there a way to change it to integers so d[1] will work?

Comment: Yes, change `d[f'{file}'] = ...` to `d[file] = ...`

Comment: Seems like you want to identify the column by number instead of by strings of column names.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries dont use indices to refence items in the dictionary likes lists and tuples.
In `for key in d: print (d[key])` if you print out key, you will see what the keys are. then you can reference them individually by `print(d["key_name"])`

To display them as `print(d[1])` change the keys to integers rather than strings `d[f'{file}']` to `d[file]`

Answer (score 0):

This is technically not an answer to your question but you can use it as a supplement.

You may be better off using dictionary comprehension and file names as the keys:

```
d = {file: pd.read_excel(file, nrows = 32, usecols="A:D").fillna("")
           for file in filenames}
#Use: d["some_file_name.xls"]
```

If you still want to use file numbers, then you need a list, not a dictionary:

```
l = [pd.read_excel(file, nrows = 32, usecols="A:D").fillna("") 
     for file in filenames]
#Use: l[0]
```